# where Images and static files for tymeleaf in a multi modul spring boot project must be stored?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, image, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i have a multi-modul spring boot project. one of the modules is web and it inclueds the thymeleaf. I store the assets like image css and javascript under resources/static/ and import the image file so "

```
<img th:src="@{/img/logo.png}" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
```

This works fine without doing any additinonal configuration in only tymeleaf project. but this structure doesnt work in multimodule project. Image can not be displayed on the page. where is the correct folder for assets in multimodel spring boot projet which uses thymeleaf. how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance[image]
[image]

i have tried to store assets under static folder in multi model spring boot project. but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the server-relative URL. Instead of context-relative. Like this:

```
<img th:src="@{~/web/img/logo.png}" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
```